# Adding Custom JQuery script in purchase order html form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment

```
pub\static\frontend\Store\name\en_US\Magento_OfflinePayments\template\payment\banktransfer.html
```

Need to add the Custom javascript or JQuery Script to disable the place order button in `banktransfer.html` file

My code looks like this,

```
<div class="field _required">
    <label data-bind="attr: {for: getCode() + '_ownerkey'}" class="label">
        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Credit key'--><!-- /ko --></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" type="text" name="payment[ownerkey]" class="input-text" value=""
               data-bind="attr: {
                                id: getCode() + '_ownerkey',
                                title: $t('Credit Key'), 
                                'data-container': getCode() + '-ownerkey',
                                'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'required':true})},
                                valueUpdate: 'keyup' "/>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action primary checkout"
                    type="submit"
                    data-bind="
                    click: placeOrder,
                    attr: {'title': $t('Place Order')},
                    enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                    "
                    disabled>
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function(jQuery)
{   
jQuery(function ($) 
{   

       jQuery(".action.primary.checkout").attr("disabled","disable");

}); });
```

Comment: jQuery is not working inside template html file you need to declare js code in your template js file.

Comment: Means should i add the custom jQuery in this method 
  
  
 \pub\static\frontend\Store\name\en_US\Magento_OfflinePayments\js\view\payment\method-renderer\banktransfer-method.js

Comment: Yes correct you need to add in above js file

Comment: If i add the custom script in the above link, then banktransfer payment method is not displaying.